# calculating average without min value, array

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array

```
 hw_grades=array([[ 57,  77,  81,  99, 100],
                  [ 56,  57,  70,  77,  91],
                  [ 62,  74,  89,  99, 100],
                  [ 21,  42,  53,  61,  65],
                  [ 37,  40,  60,  65,  81],
                  [ 75,  88,  92,  95, 100]])
```

I want to be able to return the average of each row without the lowest value (I already used `sort()` and so basically I wanna get rid of the first element of each row and then do the average

```
 def hw_grade_best(_array):
    _array.sort()
    _array[::][1:]
    result = np.average(_array, axis=1)
    return result
```

not really much of a code and the `_array[::][1:]` isn't really doing anything cause I can assume by far I am using it wrong

input
 `hw_grade_best(hw_grades)`

output I want

> array([ 89.25,  73.75,  90.5 ,  55.25,  61.5 ,  93.75])

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it eliminated the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slice the array to remove the value, then you can apply the mean function across the axis:

`hw_grades[:, 1:].mean(axis=1)`

`# array([ 89.25,  73.75,  90.5 ,  55.25,  61.5 ,  93.75])`

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
_array[::][1:]
```

you're doing nothing, because it doesn't **changes** the array, just returns (nowhere) what you have asked.

You should assign the returned array as:

```
_array = _array[::][1:]
result = np.average(_array, axis=1)
```

or just compute the average directly on it:

```
result = np.average(_array[::][1:], axis=1)
```